# Visual Studio trying to open source file that is no longer in project (fatal error C1083)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, header-only, imgui

The problem is quite simple, really. I had imgui included in my project and I'm no longer using it. However, VS still tries to open them every time I try to compile.

I removed all includes and deleted the files from my project completely. There is no mention of it anywhere. I don't have it included as an external library either (it's header-only). I've ran out of ideas.

Error log:

```
1>imgui.cpp
1>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'Source\imgui\imgui.cpp': No such file or directory
1>imgui_draw.cpp
1>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'Source\imgui\imgui_draw.cpp': No such file or directory
1>imgui_impl_glfw.cpp
1>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'Source\imgui\imgui_impl_glfw.cpp': No such file or directory
1>imgui_impl_opengl3.cpp
1>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'Source\imgui\imgui_impl_opengl3.cpp': No such file or directory
1>imgui_impl_win32.cpp
1>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'Source\imgui\imgui_impl_win32.cpp': No such file or directory
1>imgui_widgets.cpp
1>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'Source\imgui\imgui_widgets.cpp': No such file or directory
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: How did you remove these files? If you didn't remove them with Visual Studio (eg, you deleted them with an Explorer window or with the command line)  the IDE will still expect them to exist and still attempt to compile them.

Comment: I believe I removed them with VS, but I'm not sure (was 2 days ago). Would putting them back in my project and removing them again work if that's the case?

Comment: One of the views in the solution explorer should still list them if Visual Studio expects them to be there.

Comment: It wasn't listing them, which is why I was confused. Luckily adding them back into the path it tried to find them in and then excluding them seemed to do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! Turns out trying to add imgui as an additional library in an attempt to workaround another problem leaves VS thinking it exists on your source even after removing everything. Experimenting sometimes creates unexpected problems.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem following Cherno's tutorial when I downloaded the wrong version of imgui. Already having included files into the build but then deleting from file explorer caused my error. I just made phony empty files of the same name in a different folder and then just transferred them into the imgui folder to trick VS, then rebuilt. Worked fine afterwards.